# How can Make run its inside parts by calling new make?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, subprocess

Initially, when I made the question I attributed the problem to wildcards, a problem, but a bigger problem apparently looming. If I understand the error right, GNU make has no make-subprocessing so have to switch to some derivative of Boor's make. I may be understanding it wrong but I try to make this problem easier to understand.

**Makefile: makefile trying to execute parts of itself many times, the thing I mean by subprocessing**

```
all:
        make clean
        make $$(.??*)
#I want to replace below-like-things with a wildcard above
#       make .lambda
#       make .lambda_t
#
# KEY: It should run NEW make-processes! how?
clean:
        -rm .??*
.lambda:
#do something
.lambda_t:
```

Comment: So what's the reason for building your files from a different make process each time?

Comment: @Macmade: Sorry but I don't know for sure what do you mean? Boor's make suppors parallel processing, a derivation here: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/building.html. I am uncertain whether the thing I am doing in the question is even supported by GNU make, the version I was using the time I made the question. Sorry cannot yet answer but trying :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way.
You don't need to call make like that. Just declares additional targets, and use target dependancies.
Note that you can use the Make 'foreach dir' function to get files matching a pattern:

_FILES_HIDDEN = $(foreach dir,./,$(wildcard .*))